# How to find a dynamic elements using selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

```
<div id="button" data-testid="widgetButton" class=" chat-closed mobile-size__large">
```

I have elements with a special character which the Webdriver can't locate.

I'm trying to click on an item, I've tried everything.
my last try:

```
wd.get(urlSubpage);
        wd.findElement(By.cssSelector("[class='widgetLabel']"));
```

Comment: Try to partually debug it with something like ChroPath...

Comment: Which element you want to find?

Comment: There is no class `widgetLabel` in the html.

Comment: @Muzzamil I want find <button type="button" id="button-body" and click

Answer (score 0):

You can click with help of `id` with webdriver wait till element would be able to receive click.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 50);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("button-body")));
```

**Click with JS**

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("button-body"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I added but ```Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #button\-body```

Comment: @Nirwellyn  Please try click with JS as mentioned in answer. Copy paste code and try. Remove wait for element before click